# Sending multiple files from php curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl to send data and files to a web service.

From the shell I execute something like this:

```
curl -X POST -i -F "file[]=@fil1.png" -F "file[]=@file2.pdf" -F "g=GROUP" -F "o=Object" -F "m=Body." http://localhost/api/email.php
```

and the web service receives an array named "file":

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file1.png
                    [1] => file2.pdf
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                    [1] => application/pdf
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/php1SFdK3
                    [1] => /tmp/phpPmwL8p
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 74040
                    [1] => 169090
                )
        )
)
```

If I call it from php with this code:

```
    $data = [
      "g" => "GROUP",
      "o" => "object",
      "m" => "body.",
      "file[]" => $curlfile1,
      "file[]" => $curlfile2,
    ];
    
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/api/email.php',
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
      CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => "readHeader",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

the web service receives only the second file:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file2.pdf
                )
            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => application/pdf
                )
            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpPmwL8p
                )
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 169090
                )
        )
)
```

It works fine if I put the keys in the file array:

```
    $data = [
      "g" => "GROUP",
      "o" => "object",
      "m" => "body.",
      "file[0]" => $curlfile1,
      "file[1]" => $curlfile2,
    ];
```

Is there a syntax so that I can avoid to put the keys of the file array, like in the shell command?

Comment: give it a try by putting file into an array and execute the post

Comment: You should check out any HTTPClient library - writing cURL code by hand is not that simple, and a library makes your life so much easier

Comment: @NicoHaase, you mean I should use an HTTPClient library instead of cURL?

Comment: That's what I wrote. Choose one: Guzzle or Symfony's HttpClient are the most commonly used

Comment: You could, but you're 99% of the way there. Have you tried a nested array such as `"file" => [$curlfile1, $curlfile2]`?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work with `file[]` as the array key, is that in PHP array keys have to be unique. Setting `file[]` to `$curlfile1` works fine, but immediately setting the same array key to `$curlfile2` overwrites it.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, I tried it, but I receive a PHP Notice: Array to string conversion...

Comment: Well, what do you know. I learned something today. After Googling the issue, it seems that if `$curlfile1` and `$curlfile2` are CURLFile objects, you do need to manually specify the index in the array keys. So `file[0]` and `file[1]` are the way to go. If they're not CURLFiles, the answer by @IMSoP should do the trick.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. It described the _problem_ correctly, but the solution wasn't appropriate, because you're trying to send files, which use a completely different request format than just plain strings. In *principle* you could do it, but the formatting required is much more complex, and honestly at that point you're better off using an abstraction like Guzzle, or living with `file[0]` and `file[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

it *should* have worked, but doesn't, someone should complain on the php bugtracker... seems the answer is no, there's no pretty way to do it.

with that said, you could make a preprosessor function to prettify it for you... eg

```
<?php

function postArrayFixer(&$data):void{
    $original_keys = array_keys($data);
    foreach($original_keys as $key){
        $val = $data[$key];
        if(is_iterable($val)){
            foreach($val as $inner_key=>$inner_val){
                $data[$key.'['.$inner_key.']']=$inner_val;
            }
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
}

$curlfile1=new CURLFile();
$curlfile2=new CURLFile();
$data = [
  "g" => "GROUP",
  "o" => "object", 
  "m" => "body.",
  "files" => array($curlfile1, $curlfile2)
];

$data["files"][]=new CURLFile();
postArrayFixer($data);
var_export($data);
```

makes

```
array (
  'g' => 'GROUP',
  'o' => 'object',
  'm' => 'body.',
  'files[0]' =>
  CURLFile::__set_state(array(
     'name' => '',
     'mime' => '',
     'postname' => '',
  )),
  'files[1]' =>
  CURLFile::__set_state(array(
     'name' => '',
     'mime' => '',
     'postname' => '',
  )),
  'files[2]' =>
  CURLFile::__set_state(array(
     'name' => '',
     'mime' => '',
     'postname' => '',
  )),
)
```

but this *should* have been unnecessary, sigh